# Problems with tikzpicture code

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I tried to reproduce a tikz-example of a book's companion website.

Code shown below is coming from this website. The desired output can be seen in Fig. 2. However, compiling this code cunk gives me many errors and results in picture with overlapping elements. What is wrong here? If it's a general issue, I would like to share the solution with the author.

http://blogs.baylor.edu/rlatentvariable/files/2013/12/AppendixCreatingPathModels-211jclc.pdf

***MWE:***

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex,align=center,
latent/.style={circle,draw, thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=10mm},
manifest/.style={rectangle,draw, thick,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=10mm},
mean/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum
    size=10mm},
paths/.style={->, very thick, >=stealth'},
variance/.style={<->, thick, >=stealth', bend left=270, looseness=2},
]
\node [manifest] (WR) [below =of LV1]  {Word\\Reasoning};
\node [manifest] (SI) [left =of WR]  {Similarities};
\node [manifest] (IN) [left =of SI]  {Information};
\node [manifest] (MR) [right =of WR]  {Matrix\\Reasoning};
\node [manifest] (PS) [right =of MR]  {Picture\\Similarities};
\node [latent] (EIN) [below =of IN]  {Error};
\node [latent] (ESI) [below =of SI]  {Error};
\node [latent] (EWR) [below =of WR]  {Error};
\node [latent] (EMR) [below =of MR]  {Error};
\node [latent] (EPS) [below =of PS]  {Error};
\draw [paths,above] (LV1) to node   {a}   (IN);
\draw [paths,above] (LV1) to node [pos=.75]   {b}   (SI);
\draw [paths] (LV1) to node   {c}   (WR);
\draw [paths] (LV1) to node  [pos=.75]  {d}  (MR);
\draw [paths] (LV1) to node   {e}   (PS);
\foreach \e in {IN, SI, WR, MR, PS}
\draw [paths] (E\e) to node   {1}   (\e);
\foreach \x/\xlab in {EIN/f, ESI/g,EWR/h, EMR/i, EPS/j}
\draw [variance] (\x.south west) to node [swap] {\xlab}  (\x.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems preventing that from compiling:

1. The `positioning` library is not loaded, which is required to use the `left=of <nodename>` syntax. I.e. add `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`.
2. The top node, named `LV1` has disappeared from the code during copy-pasting. Look again at the code in that PDF and you'll see `\node [latent] (LV1) at (0,0) {g};` at the start of the `tikzpicture`. (The `at (0,0)` part is actually not necessary.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex,align=center,
latent/.style={circle,draw, thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=10mm},
manifest/.style={rectangle,draw, thick,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=10mm},
mean/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum
    size=10mm},
paths/.style={->, very thick, >=stealth'},
variance/.style={<->, thick, >=stealth', bend left=270, looseness=2},
]

\node [latent] (LV1) at (0,0) {g};

\node [manifest] (WR) [below =of LV1]  {Word\\Reasoning};
\node [manifest] (SI) [left =of WR]  {Similarities};
\node [manifest] (IN) [left =of SI]  {Information};
\node [manifest] (MR) [right =of WR]  {Matrix\\Reasoning};
\node [manifest] (PS) [right =of MR]  {Picture\\Similarities};
\node [latent] (EIN) [below =of IN]  {Error};
\node [latent] (ESI) [below =of SI]  {Error};
\node [latent] (EWR) [below =of WR]  {Error};
\node [latent] (EMR) [below =of MR]  {Error};
\node [latent] (EPS) [below =of PS]  {Error};
\draw [paths,above] (LV1) to node   {a}   (IN);
\draw [paths,above] (LV1) to node [pos=.75]   {b}   (SI);
\draw [paths] (LV1) to node   {c}   (WR);
\draw [paths] (LV1) to node  [pos=.75]  {d}  (MR);
\draw [paths] (LV1) to node   {e}   (PS);
\foreach \e in {IN, SI, WR, MR, PS}
\draw [paths] (E\e) to node   {1}   (\e);
\foreach \x/\xlab in {EIN/f, ESI/g,EWR/h, EMR/i, EPS/j}
\draw [variance] (\x.south west) to node [swap] {\xlab}  (\x.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```